# Options missing in vso preview Build definition

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am trying to output a build to a drop folder using the new build templates in VSO.  I'm running into trouble in that every reference I can find shows an option for "Copy to drop location" in the Options panel.  My build template contains neither that option nor the "Copy to staging" option.
[image]

I'm using an on premise build agent, so the work around of publishing artifacts to a file system is failing as well.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Copy to Drop" location was replaced with a "Publish Artifacts" build task. You can publish artifacts to any UNC path.

Comment: This always fails for our on premise server. I get an error "Unable to associate artifact with resource at location:(location)"

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing the UNC path to another drop server.  It appears to be a server config issue.